# Algebraic Identities on Matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a matrix $D$, find $C$ where
$$C+D=I_3$$

Then, find $DC$ & $D^3+C^3$.

I found $C$ and $CD$ but I am wondering if the last is correct for matrices:

$$C+D=I_3 \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (C+D)^3=I_3^3 \Leftrightarrow$$
$$ \Leftrightarrow C^3+D^3+3C^2D+3CD^2=I_3\Leftrightarrow$$
$$C^3+D^3=I_3-3CD(C+D)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that $C=\operatorname{Id}_3-D$. So\begin{align}C^3+D^3&=(\operatorname{Id}_3-D)^3+D^3\\&=\operatorname{Id}_3-3D+3D^2-D^3+D^3\\&=\operatorname{Id}_3-3D+3D^2.\end{align}

Comment: So, algebraic identities do not hold with matrices, do they?

Comment: If they didn't, I would not have been able to get an answer, right?!

Comment: You are right... I realised that when I posted the question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

We have $C=I-D$, hence $DC=D-D^2$ and $D^3+C^3=D^3+(I-D)^3=I-3D+3D^2$.